Create the characters you can write on a MacOS US English Keyboard (as another OS will read them)
Introduction
This is a small challenge I came up with while trying to make some compact code for my younger brother to use. I don't think it's particularly interesting, but I believe it presents some unique challenges because of its limited input/output requirements.
Challenge
I want to enumerate all the characters that my brother can write on his MacOS computer using only his US English keyboard, as they will be read by my Windows device. He does not have Unicode hex input enabled, so I only have to worry about things he can type using combinations of Shift and Alt/Option. These are as follows:
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¥§¨©ª«¬®¯°±´µ¶·¸º»¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõö÷øùúûüÿıŒœŸƒˆˇ˘˙˚˛˜˝Ωπ–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›⁄€™∂∆∏∑√∞∫≈≠≤≥◊ﬁﬂ

along with the Apple logo, which my device reads as � (U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER). As a list of unicode codepoints, these are
[U+0020, U+0021, U+0022, U+0023, U+0024, U+0025, U+0026, U+0027, U+0028, U+0029, U+002A, U+002B, U+002C, U+002D, U+002E, U+002F, U+0030, U+0031, U+0032, U+0033, U+0034, U+0035, U+0036, U+0037, U+0038, U+0039, U+003A, U+003B, U+003C, U+003D, U+003E, U+003F, U+0040, U+0041, U+0042, U+0043, U+0044, U+0045, U+0046, U+0047, U+0048, U+0049, U+004A, U+004B, U+004C, U+004D, U+004E, U+004F, U+0050, U+0051, U+0052, U+0053, U+0054, U+0055, U+0056, U+0057, U+0058, U+0059, U+005A, U+005B, U+005C, U+005D, U+005E, U+005F, U+0060, U+0061, U+0062, U+0063, U+0064, U+0065, U+0066, U+0067, U+0068, U+0069, U+006A, U+006B, U+006C, U+006D, U+006E, U+006F, U+0070, U+0071, U+0072, U+0073, U+0074, U+0075, U+0076, U+0077, U+0078, U+0079, U+007A, U+007B, U+007C, U+007D, U+007E, U+00A1, U+00A2, U+00A3, U+00A5, U+00A7, U+00A8, U+00A9, U+00AA, U+00AB, U+00AC, U+00AE, U+00AF, U+00B0, U+00B1, U+00B4, U+00B5, U+00B6, U+00B7, U+00B8, U+00BA, U+00BB, U+00BF, U+00C0, U+00C1, U+00C2, U+00C3, U+00C4, U+00C5, U+00C6, U+00C7, U+00C8, U+00C9, U+00CA, U+00CB, U+00CC, U+00CD, U+00CE, U+00CF, U+00D1, U+00D2, U+00D3, U+00D4, U+00D5, U+00D6, U+00D8, U+00D9, U+00DA, U+00DB, U+00DC, U+00DF, U+00E0, U+00E1, U+00E2, U+00E3, U+00E4, U+00E5, U+00E6, U+00E7, U+00E8, U+00E9, U+00EA, U+00EB, U+00EC, U+00ED, U+00EE, U+00EF, U+00F1, U+00F2, U+00F3, U+00F4, U+00F5, U+00F6, U+00F7, U+00F8, U+00F9, U+00FA, U+00FB, U+00FC, U+00FF, U+0131, U+0152, U+0153, U+0178, U+0192, U+02C6, U+02C7, U+02D8, U+02D9, U+02DA, U+02DB, U+02DC, U+02DD, U+03A9, U+03C0, U+2013, U+2014, U+2018, U+2019, U+201A, U+201C, U+201D, U+201E, U+2020, U+2021, U+2022, U+2026, U+2030, U+2039, U+203A, U+2044, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2202, U+2206, U+220F, U+2211, U+221A, U+221E, U+222B, U+2248, U+2260, U+2264, U+2265, U+25CA, U+FB01, U+FB02, U+FFFD]

Your program should take no input and return as output any permutation of the above characters. As such, all of the following are equally valid outputs:
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¥§¨©ª«¬®¯°±´µ¶·¸º»¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõö÷øùúûüÿıŒœŸƒˆˇ˘˙˚˛˜˝Ωπ–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›⁄€™∂∆∏∑√∞∫≈≠≤≥◊ﬁﬂ�

�ﬂﬁ◊≥≤≠≈∫∞√∑∏∆∂™€⁄›‹‰…•‡†„”“‚’‘—–πΩ˝˜˛˚˙˘ˇˆƒŸœŒıÿüûúùø÷öõôóòñïîíìëêéèçæåäãâáàßÜÛÚÙØÖÕÔÓÒÑÏÎÍÌËÊÉÈÇÆÅÄÃÂÁÀ¿»º¸·¶µ´±°¯®¬«ª©¨§¥£¢¡~}|{zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! 

'•ö‚›ƒõº≈¶≥πJBè≤‰ˆ®Iã8√=Ÿ“…«PêıÕ*&|UZk£_!œ’uÆ@Ùø¢{Û˚Óüä^j¡5y- 3(nËN∑ò‡⁄D¥S2FhÒîO1ûV6ç,m9ÍæÉ·¸/◊Êw∆~R)é4áÂ%˝Úl°ÿG†˘tKÈ¿Àó∞H]§`rﬁñ≠ìzv.¬»©∏ëâgcbØ÷¨Ã”eíŒ∂?´$Ç\�ÁC˛ïù±ΩªoﬂÄ}#Îµ„:àßXaMxå€ÔT™;˜<qÅ7d∫‹ú‘ˇ+—Ñ0ô[fs–ÏQÖEpÌ˙LW"ÜAi>¯Y

_Õz∆h@`òÈmóc|\á∞IŒ›d˘œ';86åƒ”-§µéX†T·$C.Ú¡Æ˚BíN{ßtSûe¿âÓ’üZπìa˜ËKG]˛±Öb)A"Yx⁄ô*+™ÍQÔı¶0ÜÒ•}4ÿÑ£uêw¢ps–¯—qøﬁ‡HÁR 5k[ΩèL“/≈FyJ≠^˙€~©ﬂ�ï°V7æúE#öªnrM…«WÊ13îgºà◊Ï‘‹´ÛÌÉ=»¨®ÄOÇ∏ˇD(U‚≥Ù‰>v<Ÿõo%√Î∫ç∑Øi2:P&9À„fù≤,∂lj!ë¥Åˆ¸Ãã¬÷Â˝ñä?

The following are invalid outputs:
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~

(only some of the characters)
D4úÉÄnxJ ]0l“ﬁƒ‹«:£*˜∏Ø¶cÃÈ•ír¥¨(63S˙˚1™R{u˝´é&"#Õ œGÅ9ÂUîÊ¯E®øfH–@ãòp†YÜ‚K”!öïsOâXg·NûQaàiÍÓ'o#&ñìÀÔÑŒt√≤˘Bæ∫„¿ﬂ°,ˆ€çb\…>Ï◊äw)≈C§;ùkÁµ�eºI¬ÛË›V[`∞≠yÎAzˇ»÷j’ÿÇ<_Ì¡Z-õvÆMΩ∂FWm%⁄L2ß∑‘åÒÚ|=‡≥ê¢Öó~ªı+ë$.üq58±∆Ùh/èô^π©—$‰TP%'"¸Ÿ!7á?}d˛

(some characters repeated)
‹ìñ∞]~äÓ_1,òètaqÙ|cıiß≥ÜóÎm{;`ºÃBÏçyxπ˘Ç®—âÆÕ©jîOp¸MV¿éÄT¡êØ∫≠!CΩ≤˝ö∂næ+"PÒ⁄‰°∏GÚ?⍼o∆†Y38£7»AªÅb™u=‡ÍË�ˇUR@Füµﬁ◊ør˙íQe:wkWH46Êv´œ5ﬂNlÈˆdã÷Œ ‚\ÉÖ>ú[}•õ≈ù/Û∑ô›%åÿ¶¥Ì–Á·¬<˜˚¯&ëXà§˛ƒï€«2Ñ-'û)‘√À*ÂZ^#Isf0…K.“¨„gh±SL¢$”Dá(’ÔzE9JŸ

(includes a character not in the list, namely ⍼)
Solutions in Python 2 or Python 3 are preferred because Python is my native programming language, but all standard languages, code-golf oriented or otherwise, are allowed (of course, no standard loopholes). Your program must finish within five seconds, and you must provide a link to a resource to run it online. Programs are scored as follows:

take the length (in bytes) of the UTF-32(-LE) representation of the source code
if your code gives the same output every time, add n to its score, where n is the smallest number of characters you have to remove from its output to make it be sorted in UTF-32 order (either increasing or decreasing)
if it can give different outputs, add 222 (the length of the output) to its score.
if your code uses only ASCII characters, you get to (ceiling-)divide its score by 2, so a score of 731 becomes 366.

If your code is bytes rather than characters (as in the case of a custom codepage) and it can be decoded with ASCII then it counts as “ASCII-only”; otherwise each byte is 4 points. An ASCII only solution will score twice its byte count as a baseline, but if its output is scrambled it gets half the penalty points as well.
Please explain how you computed your score. The lowest score wins; ties are broken by length of the UTF-8 encoding of the source code.
Baseline/Example Input and Output
Below is my current best code: Python 2, with a score of 664 (166 UTF-32 codepoints, each 4 bytes, plus 0 for giving the same result every time and that result being in UTF-32 sorted order).
print''.join(map(chr,range(32,127)))+'¡¢£¥§¨©ª«¬®¯°±´µ¶·¸º»¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõö÷øùúûüÿıŒœŸƒˆˇ˘˙˚˛˜˝Ωπ–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›⁄€™∂∆∏∑√∞∫≈≠≤≥◊ﬁﬂ�'

It takes no input and provides as output the following string:
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¥§¨©ª«¬®¯°±´µ¶·¸º»¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõö÷øùúûüÿıŒœŸƒˆˇ˘˙˚˛˜˝Ωπ–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›⁄€™∂∆∏∑√∞∫≈≠≤≥◊ﬁﬂ�


Is there a reason you require this particular website to run Python programs?

@CommandMaster It’s the most versatile online Python emulator I’m aware of that allows one to save multiline scripts and send compact corresponding URLs; if you know of any better options I’d happily include them but I need to make sure they work at least with my minimal script.

https://ato.pxeger.com/ and https://tio.run/ are often used in here

I have removed the python website requirements. Thank you for the resources! They both look really nice.

So does an ASCII only solution score twice its byte count? (i.e. ASCII characters times four to get in UTF-32 then ceil divide by two)

Also, if our code is actually bytes rather than characters then how should we score? Many golfing languages use custom code-pages and others use various standard code pages simply to make the code human-readable. Does each byte count for four points? Do we identify bytes 0-127 as "ASCII"?

@JonathanAllan If your code is bytes rather than characters and it can be decoded with ASCII then it counts as “ASCII-only”; otherwise each byte is 4 points. An ASCII only solution will score twice its byte count as a baseline, but if its output is scrambled it gets half the penalty points as well.

Scala 3, 476 code points, 217 bytes in UTF-8
("ıŒœŸƒˆˇ˘˙˚˛˜˝Ωπ–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›⁄€™∂∆∏∑√∞∫≈≠≤≥◊ﬁﬂ�".toSet++('!'to'~')++('¡'to'ÿ')--"ðÝ¤¦­²³¹¼½¾Ð×Þýþ").mkString.sorted

The code contains an unprintable soft-hyphen (U+00ad) after the ¦, here is a hexdump:
00000000  28 22 c4 b1 c5 92 c5 93  c5 b8 c6 92 cb 86 cb 87  |("..............|
00000010  cb 98 cb 99 cb 9a cb 9b  cb 9c cb 9d ce a9 cf 80  |................|
00000020  e2 80 93 e2 80 94 e2 80  98 e2 80 99 e2 80 9a e2  |................|
00000030  80 9c e2 80 9d e2 80 9e  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a1 e2 80  |................|
00000040  a2 e2 80 a6 e2 80 b0 e2  80 b9 e2 80 ba e2 81 84  |................|
00000050  e2 82 ac e2 84 a2 e2 88  82 e2 88 86 e2 88 8f e2  |................|
00000060  88 91 e2 88 9a e2 88 9e  e2 88 ab e2 89 88 e2 89  |................|
00000070  a0 e2 89 a4 e2 89 a5 e2  97 8a ef ac 81 ef ac 82  |................|
00000080  ef bf bd 22 2e 74 6f 53  65 74 2b 2b 28 27 21 27  |...".toSet++('!'|
00000090  74 6f 27 7e 27 29 2b 2b  28 27 c2 a1 27 74 6f 27  |to'~')++('..'to'|
000000a0  c3 bf 27 29 2d 2d 22 c3  b0 c3 9d c2 a4 c2 a6 c2  |..')--".........|
000000b0  ad c2 b2 c2 b3 c2 b9 c2  bc c2 bd c2 be c3 90 c3  |................|
000000c0  97 c3 9e c3 bd c3 be 22  29 2e 6d 6b 53 74 72 69  |.......").mkStri|
000000d0  6e 67 2e 73 6f 72 74 65  64                       |ng.sorted|
000000d9

Attempt This Online!

Shouldn't it be 219 UTF-8 bytes?

ATO and wc both say 217, and the hexdump also has 217 bytes, Why should it be 219?

The only way I can get it to be 476 points is if I copy your code and manually add a U+00AD after the ¦, which puts it at 219 UTF-8 bytes.

The code has a test case and works as-is. If you copy the ¦­² and paste it into wc -c, it's 6 bytes, two per character. The 476 is the number I got from iconv.

Okay that explains it. Thanks!

Python 3.8, 256 bytes, ASCII only, sorted: score = 512
c=31
J=''.join
print(J(J(chr(c:=c+dict(enumerate((54583,7251,308,869,204,1275,224),120)).get(j,j))for _ in'.'*m)for j,m in zip(b'''#2!%z|y
    
hv~     \x0d{x}''',b"_"+b''*22)))

(...there are many unprintable ASCII characters.)
Try it online!
Hex:
63 3d 33 31 0a 4a 3d 27 27 2e 6a 6f 69 6e 0a 70  |c=31.J=''.join.p|
72 69 6e 74 28 4a 28 4a 28 63 68 72 28 63 3a 3d  |rint(J(J(chr(c:=|
63 2b 64 69 63 74 28 65 6e 75 6d 65 72 61 74 65  |c+dict(enumerate|
28 28 35 34 35 38 33 2c 37 32 35 31 2c 33 30 38  |((54583,7251,308|
2c 38 36 39 2c 32 30 34 2c 31 32 37 35 2c 32 32  |,869,204,1275,22|
34 29 2c 31 32 30 29 29 2e 67 65 74 28 6a 2c 6a  |4),120)).get(j,j|
29 29 66 6f 72 20 5f 20 69 6e 27 2e 27 2a 6d 29  |))for _ in'.'*m)|
66 6f 72 20 6a 2c 6d 20 69 6e 20 7a 69 70 28 62  |for j,m in zip(b|
27 27 27 01 23 01 02 01 02 01 03 01 02 01 04 01  |'''.#...........|
02 01 02 01 03 01 02 01 03 32 21 01 25 1a 7a 01  |.........2!.%.z.|
11 01 7c 17 79 01 04 01 02 01 02 01 04 0a 09 01  |..|.y...........|
0a 68 76 7e 04 09 02 09 04 5c 78 30 64 1d 18 04  |.hv~.....\x0d...|
01 7b 78 01 7d 27 27 27 2c 62 22 5f 01 02 02 05  |.{x.}''',b"_....|
01 03 01 04 01 01 01 10 01 05 01 04 01 10 01 0b  |................|
01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 05 01 01 01 01 01 02  |................|
01 02 01 02 22 2b 62 27 01 27 2a 32 32 29 29 29  |...."+b'.'*22)))|


Vyxal 3, 147 bytes
"λʀ)0M1“"ᵇRJÞpṖ∨“;ƛᶲ⁻]⌊\:ꜝI$ᵛ8p:ᵂ∦ꜝᵛ…pf"ᵇ†5%“ᶲ²ᵛ82p"ᶜam↑⁺ṫᵃ“ᶲ0p²ᵛ87p"ᵇ1|∦ỊṚỊ“ᶲ⁻"ᶠ⁻[“ᶲ⁻ᵛ8p~₅%~ᵇᶲ:ꜝ~≈ꜝWf⌊OkP161₇R"ᶠZ|ȧẋᶜ±µ>Bfo&“ᶲ²ᴴ½⌊f161+ṡO+"≥≤≠"W∑S

Try it Online!
Output is sorted and only uses vyxal codepage. Took nearly 45 minutes to build... Uses the fact that most numbers are in a specific range, or are in ranges of length 2 or 3 with common prefixes.
explanation (old)
"λʀ)0M1“"ᵇRJÞpṖ∨“;ƛᶲ⁻]\⌊:ꜝI$ᵛ8p⌊:ᵂ∦ꜝᵛ…pf"ᵇ†5%“ᶲ²ᵛ82p⌊"ᶜam↑⁺ṫᵃ“ᶲ0p²ᵛ87p"ᵇ1|∦ỊṚỊ“ᶲ⁻⌊"ᶠ⁻[“ᶲ⁻ᵛ8p~₅%~ᵇᶲ:ꜝ~≈ꜝWf⌊OkP161₇R"ᶠZ|ȧẋᶜ±µ>Bfo&“ᶲ²ᴴ½⌊f161+ṡO+"≥≤≠"W∑S­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
"λʀ)0M1“                                                                                                                                                # ‎⁡compressed number 210216220224240 
                                                                                                                                                        # ‎⁡
                                                                                                                                                        # ‎⁡
        "ᵇRJÞpṖ∨“                                                                                                                                       # ‎⁢compressed number 338710728730732
                 ;                                                                                                                                      # ‎⁣pair the two
                  ƛᶲ⁻]                                                                                                                                  # ‎⁤stringify, split into chunks of 3
                      \                                                                                                                                 # ‎⁢⁡push the two lists of three 
                       ⌊:                                                                                                                               # ‎⁢⁢convert to number, duplicate, 
                         ꜝI                                                                                                                             # ‎⁢⁣increment and interleave
                           $ᵛ8p                                                                                                                         # ‎⁢⁤swap top of stack and prepend an 8 to each
                               ⌊:                                                                                                                       # ‎⁣⁡convert to number and duplicate
                                 ᵂ∦                                                                                                                     # ‎⁣⁢parallel apply to the bottom copy and wrap
                                    ᵛ…                                                                                                                  # ‎⁣⁣increment twice
                                   ꜝ                                                                                                                    # ‎⁣⁤increment once
                                      pf                                                                                                                # ‎⁤⁡prepend to the other list, flatten
                                                                                                                                                        # ‎⁤⁡
                                        "ᵇ†5%“                                                                                                          # ‎⁤⁢compressed number 30495060
                                              ᶲ²ᵛ82p⌊                                                                                                   # ‎⁤⁣split into pairs with an 82 prepended and converted to numbers
                                                     "ᶜam↑⁺ṫᵃ“                                                                                          # ‎⁤⁤compressed 610192130344776
                                                              ᶲ0p²                                                                                      # ‎⁢⁡⁡prepend a zero, split into pairs
                                                                  ᵛ87p                                                                                  # ‎⁢⁡⁢prepend 87 to each
                                                                      "ᵇ1|∦ỊṚỊ“                                                                         # ‎⁢⁡⁣305376402937960 compressed
                                                                                                                                                        # ‎⁢⁡⁣
                                                                               ᶲ⁻⌊                                                                      # ‎⁢⁡⁤split into triplets as numbers
                                                                                  "ᶠ⁻[“                                                                 # ‎⁢⁢⁡364482 compressed
                                                                                       ᶲ⁻ᵛ8p                                                            # ‎⁢⁢⁢split into thirds with an 8 prepended
                                                                                            ~₅%                                                         # ‎⁢⁢⁣9674
                                                                                               ~ᵇᶲ                                                      # ‎⁢⁢⁤64257
                                                                                                  :ꜝ                                                    # ‎⁢⁣⁡duplicated and incremented
                                                                                                    ~≈ꜝ                                                 # ‎⁢⁣⁢65533
                                                                                                       Wf⌊O                                             # ‎⁢⁣⁣wrap the whole stack, flatten, floor, convert to character
                                                                                                           kP                                           # ‎⁢⁣⁤all printable ascii chars
                                                                                                                                     ⌊f161+             # ‎⁢⁤⁡convert to pairs and split 
                                                                                                                  "ᶠZ|ȧẋᶜ±µ>Bfo&“                       # ‎⁢⁤⁢351217182427282947546061799293 compressed
                                                                                                                                 ᶲ²ᴴ½                   # ‎⁢⁤⁣split into pairs, split the first pair in half
                                                                                                                                       161+             # ‎⁢⁤⁤add 161
                                                                                                             161₇R                                      # ‎⁣⁡⁡range 161-256
                                                                                                                                           ṡO           # ‎⁣⁡⁢set difference, convert to characters
                                                                                                                                             +          # ‎⁣⁡⁣add to ascii chars
                                                                                                                                              "≥≤≠"     # ‎⁣⁡⁤string "≥≤≠"
                                                                                                                                                   W∑S  # ‎⁣⁢⁡wrap stack, sum and sort


Created with the help of Luminespire.

"≠≥≤" can be put in as a string, as well as any other vyxal codepage chars that arent part of a range or make up the entire range... I personally won't do this tonight but maybe soon

I guess that this scores 600?

@JonathanAllan maybe? i'm not really sure how scoring works with sbcs

Me neither really. The description starts with "take the length (in bytes) of the UTF-32(-LE) representation of the source code" which I would think applies to any encoding, including ASCII as per my question under the OP. Even if not then I think you'd be limited to the first 127 bytes to stick within ASCII (and then maybe that would still be multiplied by 2, again as per my question)... we shall see I suppose.

in theory i could use vyxal literate mode to make it ascii only but that would be kind of a pain?

I have clarified the scoring guidelines for custom codepages.

Charcoal, 113 code points, sorted, score 452
Φγκ¡¢£¥↑…´§¦­¦®¯°´±↑…·´´¦¸¦º´»↑…´¿¦Ð¦ÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜ↑…ß¦ð↑…ñ¦ü¦ýıŒœŸƒˆˇ↑…˘¦˞¦Ω´π–—‘’‚´“´””y„†‡•…‰‹›⁄€™∂∆∏∑√∞∫≈≠≤≥◊ﬁﬂ�

Attempt This Online! Explanation: Characters that are in Charcoal's code page need to be quoted with ´ to be interpreted as part of a string literal. This is the only way that ” can be printed, but I do get to save two byte by using a ”y quoted string literal at the end of the program as I can omit the closing quote. The five longest subranges (the individual characters need to be separated with ¦s except for the two adjacent subranges) are printed using ranges, and the initial printable ASCII is extracted from a predefined variable.

Charcoal -v, 269 printable ASCII bytes, sorted, score 538
forMap"A-!?,!b-!d,!f,!h-!m,!o-!r,!u-!y,!{-!|,\"!-\"1,\"3-\"8,\":-\">,\"A-\"Q,\"S-\"^,\"a,#4,#U-#V,#{,$6,'M-'N,'_-'d,)r,**,vI-vJ,vN-vP,vR-vT,vV-vX,v\,vf,vo-vp,vz,x$,y;,{],{a,{j,{l,{u,{y,|',|D,|\,|`-|a,!&o,'+E-'+F,'8n"/","Mapi/"-"ChrBaseStringl,g:UpInclusiveRangeMiniMaxi

Try it online! Works by converting from base 95. Ungolfed:
for (Map(Split("A-!?,!b-!d,!f,!h-!m,!o-!r,!u-!y,!{-!|,\"!-\"1,\"3-\"8,\":-\">,\"A-\"Q,\"S-\"^,\"a,#4,#U-#V,#{,$6,'M-'N,'_-'d,)r,**,vI-vJ,vN-vP,vR-vT,vV-vX,v\,vf,vo-vp,vz,x$,y;,{],{a,{j,{l,{u,{y,|',|D,|\,|`-|a,!&o,'+E-'+F,'8n"),
               ","), Map(Split(i, "-"), Character(BaseString(l, g)))))
    Print(:Up, InclusiveRange(Minimum(i), Maximum(i)));

Charcoal's parser doesn't like consecutive variable names so I need to leave a separator between l and g. Chr, Min and Max are just permitted abbreviations, while / is actually infix Divide, which is overloaded to be Split on strings.
